# Limitar exibição de texto em PHP

Tags: php

Quero limitar o tamanho de caracteres que aparecem, mas não estou conseguindo. Uso o:

```
<? echo $row["catname"] ?>
```

Ele pega um texto do phpMyAdmin e mostra, só que quero limitar a exibição de caracteres na página, como faço?

Answer (score 18):

Para casos em que se precise por um indicador que a `string` foi truncada,
há uma outra opção (que é quase desconhecida), que seria a função `mb_strimwidth`.

Parece que ela já foi feita para esse fim:

```
mb_strimwidth("Hello World", 0, 10, "...");
```

Resultado

> "Hello W..."

Nesse caso, é preciso notar que você tem que adicionar o número do limitador somado ao número de caracteres que serão a indicação da limitação.

Por exemplo:

```
 mb_strimwidth("Oi mundo", 0, 5, "...")
```

Exibe:

> "Oi..."

Comment: **Nota**: Quanto ao quantificador de caracteres, tenho a impressão de ter lido em algum lugar que isso é um bug.

Comment: Mas nesse caso, o restante do texto 'morre' ou ele continua ali só que escondido ?

Comment: O texto "morre" sim.

Answer (score 10):

Pode usar o [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), esta função tem 3 parâmetros.

> substr(string, inicio, fim);

A **string** é o input que tem, o **inicio** é a posicao inicial e o **fim** é a posicao final.

No caso do segundo ou terceiro parametros: sendo negativo, ele conta posicoes a partir do fim. Se fôr positivo, conta a partir do inicio.

Exemplos:

```
echo substr("abcdef", 0, 2); // ab
echo substr("abcdef", 0, 4); // abcd
echo substr("abcdef", 0, -2); // abcd
```

Comment: Como eu posso usar isso no código <? echo $row["catname"] ?> ?

Comment: @user7329:  `<?php echo substr($row["catname"], 0, 2); ?>` só falta ajustar com o comprimento que quer.

Comment: Muito bom! @Sergio

Answer (score 8):

A solução mais universal é esta:

```
mb_substr ( string $str , int $start , [ int $length [, string $encoding ]] )
```

A função `substr` é limitada a encodings *single byte*, e vai ter problemas com *strings* com caracteres especiais em encodings como 'UTF-8' (para ISO ela funciona bem). Já a `mb_substr` conta por caracteres, e não *bytes*, sendo mais adequada para código portável.

Uso com ISO-8859-1:

```
echo mb_substr( 'Acentuação faz diferença', 4, 10, 'ISO-8859-1' );
```

Uso com UTF-8:

```
echo mb_substr( 'Acentuação faz diferença', 4, 10, 'UTF-8' );
```

**Importante**: o último parâmetro normalmente pode ser omitido, para casos em que a aplicação esteja globalmente configurada para usar um encoding específico (o que é desejável).

Mais detalhes no manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-substr.php

Relacionadas:

> [Como mostrar somente "x" caracteres em uma div?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110953/70)

> [Nao consigo limitar texto com caracteres japoneses](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117961/70)

Comment: Seu imitão! Viu o meu comentário na outra resposta, né! +1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Vc indica duplicata, comenta e não responde? :P

Comment: Você não vai linkar a sua outra resposta? Acho que "relacionar" as perguntas seria legal :)

Comment: @Bacco não é devido ao PHP, é por causa da parte CSS que o Wallace citou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117962/3635

Answer (score 6):

Faça assim:

```
<?php
echo substr($row["catname"], 0, 20);//Apenas os primeiros 20 caracteres
```