# Como mostrar somente "x" caracteres em uma div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde será de publicações, mas gostaria que, em cada publicação, mostra-se "x" caracteres, e passando desse valor, mostra-se um botão escrito "Mostrar mais", igual à do Facebook.

Se alguém souber como fazer isso ficarei muito grato.

Exemplo:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed dolor
>   molestie, suscipit quam in, efficitur ante. Praesent feugiat rhoncus
>   tellus, in rhoncus nisl...
>  [Mostrar mais](http://#)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, há várias formas de se fazer isso. Por exemplo:

- Mostrando conteúdo parcial baseado na altura. Você fixa a altura do elemento e o botão ou link "Mostrar mais" simplesmente deixa a altura completa.
- Usar um script para "cortar" o texto e guardar o original, que será novamente exibido quando se clicar no botão ou link.
- Renderizar o texto original oculto e o texto cortado visível e simplesmente fazer a troca dos elementos ao clicar no link.
- Renderizar a página com os textos cortados e carregar o conteúdo completo via Ajax.

Cada abordagem tem vantagens e desvantagens, tendo diferentes níveis de complexidade de implementação.

A abordagem pode variar ainda dependendo do conteúdo das publicações, isto é, se houver tags HTML ou algum conteúdo dinâmico.

Supondo que você queira evitar novos acessos ao servidor, que um pouco mais de texto aumentando o tamanho da página não seja problema para você e que você realmente queira limitar por quantidade de caracteres, a segunda ou terceira opções são mais razoáveis.

## Exemplo

Partindo da segunda abordagem, fiz um script bem simples que corta os textos das `div`s na inicialização da página e adiciona automaticamente um link "Leia mais".

O corte no texto faz uma busca com expressões regulares para contar a quantidade de espaços até encontrar a enésima palavra

```js
var wordLimit = 50;

$(function() {
  
  //trata o conteúdo na inicialização da página
  $('.show-summary').each(function() {
    var post = $(this);
    var text = post.text();
    //encontra palavra limite
    var re = /[\s]+/gm, results = null, count = 0;
    while ((results = re.exec(text)) !== null && ++count < wordLimit) { }
    //resume o texto e coloca o link
    if (results !== null && count >= wordLimit) {
      var summary = text.substring(0, re.lastIndex - results[0].length);
      post.text(summary + '...');
      post.data('original-text', text);
      post.append('<br/><a href="#" class="read-more">Leia mais</a>');
    }
  });
  
  //ao clicar num link "Leia mais", mostra o conteúdo original
  $('.read-more').on('click', function() {
    var post = $(this).closest('.show-summary');
    var text = post.data('original-text');
    post.text(text);
  });
  
});
```

```css
.show-summary {
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div class="show-summary">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</div>
<div class="show-summary">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</div>
<div class="show-summary">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit</div>
<div class="show-summary">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem   accusantium</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, sou leigo em JS mas vou fazer o máximo para aprender.

Answer (score 9):

### Usando CSS

O CSS não tem um jeito específico para contar "x" caracteres, mas tem algumas coisas que podem te ajudar um bocado:

- `overflow:hidden` faz com que o conteúdo seja cortado quando não couber num determinado bloco
- `text-overflow:ellipsis` faz com que o texto cortado seja indicado com reticências (`...`).
- *radio buttons* ou *checkboxes* podem fazer o papel de botões "liga-desliga" para o CSS.

  Use o *radio* para quando for mostrar um bloco por vez, use o *checkbox* quando o usuário puder expandir vários blocos simultaneamente.

### Demonstração funcional

Partindo dos conceitos acima, vamos aplicar um pouco mais de CSS e construir um protótipo funcional:

- `white-space:nowrap` faz com que o texto não quebre, forçando o corte dele ao final da `<div>`.
- o `input:checked + p {white-space:normal}` serve para que o parágrafo imediatamente em seguida do *radiobutton* selecionado mostre a frase toda.
- por questão de estética, escondemos os *radiobuttons* da tela, então vamos usar um "controle remoto" HTML, que é o `<label for="">`. Quando você clica num `label` que tem um `for`, é como se estivesse clicando no próprio elemento indicado, ativando-o.

```css
.mostrarmais p {
  width:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin:5px 0 0 0;
}

.mostrarmais input {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:-1000px;
}

.mostrarmais input:checked + p {
  white-space:normal;
}

.mostrarmais input:checked + p + label {
  display:none;
}

label {
  color:#fff;
  background:#39f;
  margin:0;
}

* {}
```

```html
<div class="mostrarmais">
  <input type="radio" name="mostrarmais" id="m1">
  <p>Texto longo que vai ser escondido com CSS usando a propriedade overflow</p>
  <label for="m1">Mostrar mais</label>
  <input type="radio" name="mostrarmais" id="m2">
  <p>Texto longo que vai ser escondido com CSS usando a propriedade overflow</p>
  <label for="m2">Mostrar mais</label>
  <input type="radio" name="mostrarmais" id="m3">
  <p>Texto longo que vai ser escondido com CSS usando a propriedade overflow</p>
  <label for="m3">Mostrar mais</label>
  <input type="radio" name="mostrarmais" id="m0" checked="checked">
  <p></p>
  <label for="m0">Esconder tudo</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, você me ajudou demais, obrigado mesmo!

Comment: @pxntxs. tem outras maneiras, procurei mostrar com CSS puro para você pegar as idéias básicas, e adaptar para o seu caso real. O importante é você entender o funcionamento.

Comment: Entendi. Valeu mesmo!