# Esconder e revelar texto usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho uma `div` que tem uma notícia, eu preciso esconder uma parte do texto quando o arquivo for lido pelo navegador, além disso o usuário poderá ver o texto completo se quiser clicando em "Ver Mais" que é uma tag `<a>` e depois torna-lo reduzido. Cheguei a isto:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//quando a pagina for carregada o texto da notícia será reduzido a 100 letras apenas.
$(document).ready(function(){
    txt = document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML;
    var txt2 = txt.substr(0,100);
    var complemento = '...';
    txt3 = txt2 + complemento;
    document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML = txt3;
});
    function Mostrar(){
       if(txt<txt3){
           document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML = txt;
           document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML = 'Mostrar Menos'; 
       }else{
           document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML = txt3;
           document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML = 'Mostrar Mais'; 
       }
}
```

Com isso já dá pra esconder o texto e abri-lo quando a função `mostrar` for chamada, mas quando a função é chamada novamente para dessa vez esconder o texto ela não funciona, alguém sabe me dizer o porque?

Penso que o problema está na verificação da condicional, mas quando eu mudo os operadores ainda assim não funciona.

Comment: Seria melhor usar ellipsis no overflow, e mudar só o estilo da div, não? Pode fazer isso com CSS puro, sem JS, segue demonstração funcional aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/110958/70

Answer (score 2):

No if, você deveria comprar o tamanho do texto (em caracteres) e não como se fossem do tipo inteiro. Algo assim:

```
if(txt.length < txt3.length) //aqui, eu verifico a quantidade de caracteres no texto.
```

Comment: `if(txt<txt2 ){` também funciona, veja o executar na minha resposta

Answer (score 1):

**Você não precisa disso**

```
var complemento = '...';
txt3 = txt2 + complemento;
```

> No mais, a resposta do `dvd` está corretíssima, veja

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   txt = document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML;
   txt2 = txt.substr(0,100)+'...';
   document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML = txt2;

  if(txt<txt2 ){
    document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML = txt;
    document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML = 'Mostrar Menos'; 
  }else{
     document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML = txt2;
     document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML = 'Mostrar Mais'; 
  }
});
    
function Mostrar(){

   if(document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML == 'Mostrar Mais'){
     document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML = txt;
     document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML = 'Mostrar Menos'; 
   }else{
     document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML = txt2;
     document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML = 'Mostrar Mais'; 
   }

}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <p id="texto-principal-noticia">
    O que é Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.
    </p>
    <button id="link-noticia" onclick="Mostrar()">Mostrar Mais</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode comparar diretamente o `innerHTML` no elemento `#link-noticia`:

```
function Mostrar(){
   if(document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML == 'Mostrar Mais'){
     document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML = txt;
     document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML = 'Mostrar Menos'; 
   }else{
     document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML = txt3;
     document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML = 'Mostrar Mais'; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Esse if else  com Operador condicional ternário como ficaria? : )

Comment: `document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML == 'Mostrar Mais' ?
     (document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML = txt,
     document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML = 'Mostrar Menos' )
   :
     (document.getElementById('texto-principal-noticia').innerHTML = txt,
     document.getElementById('link-noticia').innerHTML = 'Mostrar Mais')
   ;`

Comment: Rapaz eu estava colocando `ponto e virgula ao invés de `virgula`. Mas nesse caso para maior legibilidade o `if else` fica bem melhor

Comment: Sim. O ternários nestes casos não valem a pena. Até porque o cara pode depois querer incluir alguma outra coisa no `if` e fica complicado de ler, como vc disse.