# Não consigo limitar texto com caracteres japoneses

Tags: php, css

Estou tentando limitar o texto "em japones" que vai ser exibido em alguns lugares da pagina, nao parece que o php consiga lidar bem com este tipo de caractere.

**Exemplo de php**:

> echo substr("あえいうお", 0, 3);

Aqui mostra apenas "あ" e, deveria mostrar "あえい", ou seja 3 caracteres.

**Entao tentei com css:**

> style="overflow: hidden; width:105px;"

neste caso ele simplesmente ignora e nao limita nada, onde todo o texto com caractes japoneses vai para a tela.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Funções de *string*

Você está usando a função errada. A função `substr` é para usar com encodings de 1 *byte* por caractere, como ISO-8859-1.

As funções para *multibyte* tem o prefixo `mb_`.

O correto:

```
echo mb_substr("あえいうお", 0, 3);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/HcGNah)**.

A mesma coisa vale para `mb_strlen`, e a maioria das outras funções de string.

### Sobre o *overflow*

Se você não evitar a quebra de linha, o *hidden* por si só não resolve.

Veja um exemplo que funciona:

```html
Com quebra de linha:
<div style="overflow: hidden; width:105px; border:1px solid red;">
それは隠されていました</div>
Sem quebra de linha:
<div style="overflow: hidden; width:105px; border:1px solid red; white-space:nowrap;">
それは隠されていました</div>
```

Comment: nossaaa! valeu muiiito!  como eu procurei isso e nao encontrei!! 
briogadao!

Comment: Alias, esse lance que colocar um codigo junto, como exemplo e funcionando eh simplementes demais... 

a gente como noob tem muita dificuldade.....   obrigado por ser claro e objetivo!

Comment: Nem sempre a gente consegue, mas tamos aí pra isso ;)

Comment: Continuando com o topico, gostaria de saber se ao **invez de 105px**, eu possa usar uma **quantidade de caracteres**, por exemplo 10 caracteres?

Comment: dei sequencia a pergunta aqui no seguinte topico:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118183/como-limitar-exibicao-de-texto-em-uma-div-por-qtd-de-caracteres

Comment: Eu acho parecida demais pra ser uma nova pergunta. De qq forma, nao dá pra fazer isso com CSS só. O que dá pra fazer é um misto de CSS e PHP, pra esconder uma parte, mas mostrar quando clicado. E já tem isso respondido aqui no site. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110953/como-mostrar-somente-x-caracteres-em-uma-div/110958?s=3|0.0415#110958