# Limitar exibição de texto por quantidade de caracteres com CSS

Tags: css, html5

Amigos, normalmente o `overflow: hidden;` tem um limite de texto pelo tamanho da `DIV` dele, digamos 105 pixels...
exemplo:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width:105px; border:1px; white-space:nowrap;">
    teste de texto de teste de texto de teste de texto de teste de texto 
</div>
```

Logo minha pergunta: Seria possivel fazer isso mas, com um limite por quantidade de caracteres? digamos 5 caracteres?
por exemplo:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width:5em; border:1px; white-space:nowrap;">
    teste de texto de teste de texto de teste de texto de teste de texto  
</div>
```

Mas não funcionou

ps: essa pergunta da sequencia ao tópico: 
[Nao consigo limitar texto com caracteres japoneses](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117961/nao-consigo-limitar-texto-com-caracteres-japoneses)

Comment: a minha resposta foi suficiente para responder seu problema?

Answer (score 10):

É possível obter um resultado semelhante utilizando a unidade `ch`, não seria exatamente por número de caracteres, mas seria bem próximo. Isso acontece por que a medida é feita pela quantidade de `0` definidas no glyph que gera a fonte. Algo semelhante a isso `f039` (usado no FontAwesome) ou assim `U+0030`.

> 'ch' Relative to width of the "0" (zero)

[Fonte](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Devido ao fato de ser medido pelo glyph e não pelo caracter propriamente dito, essa medida pode variar de fonte para fonte, ou seja, pode ser que apenas mudando a fonte do projeto a quantidade de caracteres exibida seja diferente.

Aqui está um exemplo do código:

```
p {
  max-width: 15ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/6vLprqys/

Note que `p` possui uma largura máxima de `15ch`, o que faz com que a **linha quebre** após o 15º `0` obtido na análise do glyph, o restante do código apenas garante que não fique visível essa quebra de linha e que seja adicionado os 3 pontos ao final da linha. Se você não quiser essa exibição dos 3 pontos, basta remover a propriedade `text-overflow`, porém pode ter um comportamento estranho e quebrar no "meio" da letra.

Com o uso do text-overflow, é possivel quebrar exatamente no caracter, dando uma apresentação melhor (pelo menos nos que testei).

Agora, se você deseja quebrar exatamente no 15º caracter independente de fonte, etc.. Somente com CSS não será possível.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 4):

Use a propriedade text-overflow

```css
#div1 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#div2 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<p>Exemplos abaixo.</p>

<p>Esta div tem a propriedade "text-overflow:clip":</p>
<div id="div1">Este é um texto grande que não caberia na caixa e usando a propriedade</div>

<p>Esta div tem a propriedade "text-overflow:ellipsis":</p>
<div id="div2">Este é um texto grande que não caberia na caixa e usando a propriedade</div>
```

Ou faça isso usando php!!
blog.thiagobelem.net/limitando-textos 
Conseguirá fazer isso usando php, acima existe um link mostrando como faz.

Comment: err... desculpe... eu nao entendi... foi isso mesmo que eu fiz.... ou nao?  soh que, PRECISO que o limite... seja por caracteres.... e nao por tamanho... 
certo?

Comment: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/limitando-textos

Conseguirá fazer isso usando php, acima existe um link mostrando como faz.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Lucas Henrique Dutra, quebrou um galhao! Mas eu realmente tinha esperancas de poder resolver com CSS...