# Função para resumir string no php

Tags: php

Bom montei a seguinte função para resumir uma string no php.

```
function resumo($string,$chars) {
if (strlen($string) > $chars) {
    while (substr($string, $chars, 1) <> ' ' && ($chars < strlen($string))) {
        $chars++;
    }
}
return substr($string, 0, $chars);
}

echo resumo("bla bla bla bla bla", 4);
```

Bom o problema que estou tendo é o seguinte. Eu informa a quantidade de no máximo 4 letras e a função esta me retornando mais letras.

E sempre que a sting for resumida que quero adicionar (...) três pontos.
Se eu informar uma string que não for preciso resumir não é necessário adicionar os três pontos.

Comment: Não entendi pq precisa daquele `while`, não seria só retornar o `substr()` ?

Comment: Isso facilita muito as coisas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169912/3635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function resumo($string, $chars) {
    if (strlen($string) > $chars)
        return substr($string, 0, $chars).'...';
    else
        return $string;
}

echo resumo("abcde", 4);
```

**Saída**

> abcd...

Você também pode utilizar a função [`mb_strimwidth`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php), você pode usa-lá desta forma:

```
function resumo($string, $chars) {
    return mb_strimwidth($string, 0, $chars + 3, "...");
}
```

Conforme a resposta do [@Wallace](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169912/3635)

Comment: Curioso que a saída resumida ficou maior que a entrada xD kkk

Comment: kkkk bem isso, para evitar isso poderia somar a variável `char` com 2. Evitaria esse problema

Comment: Aliás, sua resposta foi sinalizada como qualidade baixa em relação a tamanho/conteúdo. Eu recomendo que além do código você coloque alguma explicação sobre o mesmo.

Comment: @RobertoFagundes era isso mesmo, obrigado.

Comment: @HugoBorges isto não vai funcionar bem com unicode, ainda recomendo que teste `mb_strimwidth`, como na resposta do Wallace: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169912/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o problema é, como vou fazer para aparecer os pontos apenas se tiver que abreviar? Tem como você posta um resposta ai eu ja marco ele como solucionada.

Comment: @HugoBorges exatamente isso que a função faz, se passar do limite ela adiciona os tres pontos, caso contrário não. Não é necessário postar uma resposta nova e nem é mais possivel, pois a pergunta já é marcada como dup e a resposta do Wallace lhe resolve o problema, se quiser vote up na resposta do Wallace para agradecer-lhe sobre a colaboração com a dica. ;)

Comment: Alterei a resposta adicionando um exemplo

Comment: Obrigado, foi corrigido

Comment: @RobertoFagundes editado, recomendo ainda que ajuste o código de limitação fazendo a conta de caracteres, mas ae é opcional.

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer

Comment: @RobertoFagundes não entendeu o que eu disse sobre "editado" ou sobre como usar a função?

Comment: Não entendi este comentário: `recomendo ainda que ajuste o código de limitação fazendo a conta de caracteres, mas ae é opcional.`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ficou assim a função. `function resumo($string, $chars) {
 
 // Calcula os pontos
 $chars += 3;
 
 // Retorno
 return mb_strimwidth($string, 0, $chars, "...");
}`

Comment: @HugoBorges não precisa, o teu código esta correto, é que eu não tinha entendido direito, mas pelo que testei esta ok ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pode simplificar sua função apenas com `substr()` ou `mb_substr()` como retorno e mudar a assinatura da função para adicionar os `...` caso nenhum argumento seja passado:

```
function resumo($string, $chars=0) {
    if(!mb_strlen($string)) return '';
    return  $chars == 0 ? $string : substr($string, 0, $chars)  .'...';
}

echo resumo("bla bla bla bla bla", 4); //Output = "bla ..."
echo resumo("bla bla bla bla bla");    //Output = "bla bla bla bla bla"
echo resumo("bl", 5);                  //Output = "bl..."
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/JlGc).

Comment: era isso mesmo, obrigado.

Comment: Só tem um detalhe, os (...) só pode aparecer se a sting for resumida.